# Find the expression for the following coeffiecient

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find an expression for the following coefficient

$$[x^{n}](1-5x^2)^{3m}$$

I know I need to use the binomial theorem with something like

$$[x^{n}]\sum\limits_{k=0}^{3m} {3m \choose k}(-5x^2)^k $$

but I'm not sure what I'm doing with the 3m exponent is correct or what to do with the x^2

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does that mean the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1-5x^2)^{3m}?$

Comment: If $n=2k$, then $[x^n](1-5x^2)^{3m}=\binom{3m}{k}(-5)^k$. If $n$ is odd, then $[x^n](1-5x^2)^{3m}=0$.

Comment: I'm looking for an expression for the nth coefficient

Comment: I'm making a guess that the solution is $${3m \choose n/2}(-5)^{n/2}$$

Comment: That is correct, since $k=n/2$. But you have to specify that it is $0$ for odd $n$.

Comment: it's 0 for odd n as a result of k=n/2 since k must be an integer?

Comment: @guest: since $$\left(1-5x^2\right)^{3m}=\sum_{k=0}^{3m}\binom{3m}{k}\left(-5x^2\right)^k$$ the exponent of $x$ is $2k$; that is the only exponents of $x$ that appear are even.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum you have written is the full expansion of $(1-5x^2)^{3m}$.  You don't need a sum, as only one term will have a power of $x^n$, which is the one where $k=\frac n2$.  If $n$ is odd, there won't be one.  If $n$ is even, just take the proper term, express the binomials in terms of factorials (if you want) and show the power of $5$.